# How to share a post to facebook, from my own website? (Without use of an external window)

Tags: php, facebook

Facebook seemingly blocks almost all use of iframes, I have tried using the sharer.php:

```
<a class="iframe cboxElement" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ $link->long_url }}">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a>
```

No luck, seems very scarce information online on how to do, I've noticed that bitly has found a way to do this.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Comment: @Philibobby Yes, that creates an external popup window, my question was,  is it possible to do it without one.